# GNS3 installation fails in MX Linux

Tags: linux, python

I am using [MX Linux](https://mxlinux.org/) which has Python versions 2.6 and 3.7.

In order to use the [GNS3 network simulator app,](https://www.gns3.com/), I need Python versions 3.4 or 3.5.

How to I get GNS3 working despite the difference in Python versions?

Answer (score 0):

The GNS3 install procedure at https://docs.gns3.com/1QXVIihk7dsOL7Xr7Bmz4zRzTsJ02wklfImGuHwTlaA4/index.html explains you  must create a symbolic link for python 3.5 using python3.7. Please follow that procedure.